# Issue with pyinstaller, transforming .py file into .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I wrote a python script with the following libraries:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import Button
```

And when I put this code in my terminal:

```
pyinstaller dcscriptextra1.py --onefile -w --paths=lib
```

It makes the .exe file, but when I launch it, I get this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dcscriptextra1.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

I think this means that it didnt import the libraries with the .exe file.

I don't know what to do right now. Does somebody know how to fix this issue?

**Note**
I am running python 3.12.2
I am using pyinstaller 6.5.0

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541812/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyautogui-only-in-pyinstaller-exe) help at all?